# Cannot add row to datagridview in delegate function

Tags: c#, datagridview, delegates

I am trying to add a new row to an existing datagridview in a public function.  Whenever I try to access any data properties of the datagridview I get null values. The datasource property is null so I cannot add a new element to it.  I have created a new datagridviewrow, but the CreateCells method does not copy columns and throws an index out of bounds error.  Does anyone know what might be wrong with what I am trying to do here?

Here is the code for the entire function:

```
public void AddToGrid(Attendance newRecord)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGridViewRow newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
            newRow.CreateCells(AttendanceGrid);
            newRow.Cells[1].Value = newRecord.EmployeeNumber;
            newRow.Cells[2].Value = newRecord.ScheduledDate;
            newRow.Cells[3].Value = newRecord.SIn;
            newRow.Cells[4].Value = newRecord.SOut;
            newRow.Cells[5].Value = newRecord.AIn;
            newRow.Cells[6].Value = newRecord.AOut;
            newRow.Cells[7].Value = newRecord.RecordCode;
            newRow.Cells[8].Value = newRecord.ReasonCode;
            newRow.Cells[9].Value = newRecord.Comments;

            AttendanceGrid.Rows.Add(newRow);
            AttendanceGrid.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ":  " + ex.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone see a problem with what I am doing?

Comment: Are you using a datasource such as a Datatable for the DatagridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a datasource for the DatagridView such as a DataTable.

You then bind that DataTable to the Datagridview via a Binding Source.

You can the add new rows to the DataTable, which will then reflect in the Datagrid automatically.